# What regex can I use to match CSS and JavaScript links in an HTML document?

Tags: javascript, regex, gulp, minify

I'm using a simple gulp task for "minifying" my CSS and JS files. The task adds a `.min` suffix to the name of the minified files. I'd like to update the HTML to point to the new, compressed files e.g:

**Change this:**

```
<link ...  href="...some_name.css ..." ...>
```

**To this:**

```
<link ...  href="...some_name.min.css ..." ...>
```

I use [gulp-string-replace plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-string-replace), but I can't figure out the right regex to target JS and CSS links. I don't want to hardcode filenames and I obviously can't just match for the strings `.css` or `.js`.

**Sample tasks:**

```
var replace = require('gulp-string-replace');

gulp.task('replace_1', function() {
  gulp.src(["./config.js"]) // Any file globs are supported
    .pipe(replace(new RegExp('@env@', 'g'), 'production'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./build/config.js'))
});

gulp.task('replace_2', function() {
  gulp.src(["./index.html"])
    .pipe(replace(/version(={1})/g, '$1v0.2.2'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./build/index.html'))
});

gulp.task('replace_3', function() {
  gulp.src(["./config.js"])
    .pipe(replace(/foo/g, function () {
        return 'bar';
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./build/config.js'))
});
```

Comment: Can you please also add examples of strings that should be matched and strings that should not be matched?

Comment: Any form of CSS and script link, <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/style.css"> or <link href="assets/css/style.css"> or <link href="assets/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">, etc

Comment: Sure, but do you also want to rewrite absolute CSS links like `<link href="https://cdn.example.com/style.css">` ? Or don't you have any kind of absolute links?

Comment: The only bits I need to change are file extensions: .css to .min.css and .js to .min.js.

Answer (score 0):

This would solve your question, but would include all css file links.

```
replace(/href=\"(\S*)\.css\"/gi, 'href="$1.min.css"')
```

Comment: ... and of course it will also replace the text in `you can find <tt>href="bootstrap.css"</tt> in many locations`", which likely isn't what the OP wanted. But I agree it's close enough.

Answer (score 0):

The usual way to do this would be to incorporate something like the [gulp-processhtml](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-processhtml)
plugin in your workflow.  It is designed to do exactly what you are doing.

```
  <!-- build:css style.min.css -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
  <!-- /build -->
```

becomes simply

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.min.css">
```

Here is a gulp 4.0 task I use when moving a development version of the html to a deployment directory:

```
var stripComments = require("gulp-strip-comments");
var modifyHTMLlinks = require("gulp-processhtml");
var addVersionString = require("gulp-version-number");
var print = require('gulp-print').default;

function processHTML() {
  return gulp.src(paths.html.src)
    .pipe(print())

    // modifyHTMLlinks: remove browserSync script link
    // update css/js links to .min.css or .min.js
    .pipe(modifyHTMLlinks())

    .pipe(stripComments.html(stripOptions))

    // add ?v=dateTime stamp to css and js links
    .pipe(addVersionString(versionConfig))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.html.deploy));
}
```

This seems much more foolproof than messing with regex's but perhaps you have some reason to avoid such a plugin?

Comment: I do. Every time you add a file, change it's name you have to remember to update the script.